# ruby rails model url validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

After a bunch of research and trying different gems I ended up rolling with the following:

```
  validates :url,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 245 },
            format: { with: URI.regexp(%w(http https)), message: :bad_url_format }
```

This correctly validates the http:// and https:// prefixes but it allows any type of domain extension i.e. http://go.forever.

Is this considered normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's normal for URL validations. Given the recent [expansion of top-level domains](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2-2014-01-21-en) to over one hundred, and the likelihood of that list to grow, it would be pretty cumbersome and brittle to try and enforce a list of allowed TLDs.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to validate the domain extension, I would do something along the lines of this.

Using a custom validation

```
validate :correct_url_extension

EXTENSIONS = %w(com org gov blah foo blah bar)

def correct_url_extension
  ext = url.split(".")[-1] #extension should always be at the end (parse here)
  return EXTENSIONS.include?(ext) ? true : false
end
```